# reset margins and paddings between columns in Neat

Tags: bourbon, neat

I am new to neat. 
I want to know what i am doing wrong here as i am trying to reset the auto margins and paddings between columns in the grid .
this is my code

```
$grid-columns: 12;
$gutter: 0px;
```

The grid column variables are working but the gutter is not. can u help me out.
thanks.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try setting the gutter before importing neat. Eg:

```
$gutter: 0em;
@import "neat/neat";
$grid-columns: 12;
```

Comment: hey thanks man. if you like the question, please upvote it.Thanks.